# Swift Callback change UIViewController Label

Tags: ios, swift, callback

I started to study Swift for IOS yesterday and I'm trying to make a simple login app. This is my swift file

```
import Foundation
import SwiftHTTP

func printSomething (sentence: String) {
   println(sentence);
}

func makeLoginCall(user: String, pwd: String, doneFunction : (Bool) -> Void) {

    var url : String = "myurl"

    var request = HTTPTask()

    request.requestSerializer = JSONRequestSerializer()
    request.responseSerializer = JSONResponseSerializer()

    request.POST(url,
         parameters : ["username": user, "password": pwd],
         success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
              if let dict = response.responseObject as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            println("\(dict)")
            doneFunction(true)
        }
        }, failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
            println("error \(error)")
            doneFunction(false)
     })

 }
```

and this is my ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var userTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func loginButtonCallback(sender: AnyObject) {
    checkLogin()
}

func checkLogin() {
    var user : String = userTextField.text
    var pass : String = passTextField.text

    makeLoginCall(user, pass, printResult)
}

func printResult(result: Bool) -> Void {
    println("print result function started")
    if (result) {
        resultLabel.text = "Login done"
    } else {
        resultLabel.text = "Login wrong"
    }
}
}
```

Now the printResult function is called but the label won't change. 
What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `printResult` function runs asynchronously.

All UI changes must be dispatched to the main queue

To get back to the main queue use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    doneFunction(…)
});
```

inside your completion block of the POST request

Comment: Great! Now it works. But is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Since you dispatched it by using a asynchronous function, this is indeed the way to go. You could also (as Krishna suggested) put the dispatch function inside your doneFunction, this will make it so you will only have to have the dispatch code one time.

Answer (score 2):

Write your code in main thread which will interact with UI like this :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        if (result) {
                  resultLabel.text = "Login done"
      } else {
              resultLabel.text = "Login wrong"
    }
})
```